# How to set relative path with java?

Tags: java

I have a java application(Single jar file) and I want to get relative path to my conf file. Is there any way to get relative path to my conf file?

Here is my main class code; (under src\com\pro\code)

```
String confPath = "relative path to conf file";
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(
                           new FileInputStream(confPath), "UTF8"));
```

My config file is under

```
src\com\pro\conf
```

path.

Comment: Do you have a maven project? As far as I see this conf file is in yours sources.

Comment: @freedev no its not maven. Just a simple java project.

Comment: and is the file added in your jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your configuration file in your Jar file?

If yes, it's not a file, don't try accessing it like that.

Get it this way:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/com/pro/conf/config.file.name");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Assuming that `src` is just a way to gather your sources together and not the name of a package. If it is part your package name, then use `/src/com/pro/conf/config.file.name` in `getResource(...)`.

Comment: Yes my configuration file in my Jar file.

Answer (score 0):

If your conf file is where you say it is,

```
String confPath = "src/com/pro/code/conffile.conf";
```

should work, if your application's root directory contains the '/src' folder and the file itself is called `conffile.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(    
        this.getClass()
        .getResourceAsStream("com/pro/conf/filename"), "UTF8"));
```